# Induced current in a closed loop in opposing directions

Tags: magnetic-fields, electricity, electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction

When a magnetic field is given to the loop as in the figure(sorry for the horrible drawing);
[image]

I'm told that there will be an anticlockwise current induced in both the 'inner' and 'outer' loops, resulting in opposing currents, and since the area of the outer loop is larger, the net current flows so that it's anticlockwise in the outer loop.

I'm confused. Isn't there just one *closed* loop here? Doesn't a circuit have to be *closed* for current to be induced in it?

Comment: As far as I know, it doesn't rotate or anything- it's just a loop with a field provided to it. I think the question's only asking about the instant in which the field is provided, since only then would a current be induced.

Comment: But if the loop is perpendicular to the field, and the  loop is stationary, why would there be an induced emf?

Comment: Lenz's law- doesn't a current form to oppose the inbound flux?

Comment: That’s my point Harry. The conditions you have stated will result in no current. Something has to vary. I’ll update my answer since I now think I know what you are asking. Cheers.

Comment: could you please specify what you mean by inner and outer loop? I only see one closed loop @josephh

Comment: @joseph h: yes, something has to vary for the situation to be the same for extended periods of time- which as I said, I think it isn't. This's all the info in the question, so it seems likely the question is only dealing with an instant of time dt in which flux changed, and electric current was induced. Buraian: exactly, isn't there just one loop, in which current should flow in an anticlockwise manner?

Comment: oops I pinged dr Joseph when I meant to ping you @HarryHolmes but yeah I agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity assume that magnetic field is uniform in a downward direction and **increasing** in magnitude at a constant rate. I will explain in a minute why I have made this assumption from the information that you have provided.

Without saying anything about the nature of the loop other than it is of constant area $A$, the rate of change of magnetic flux is $\frac {d(BA)}{dt} = A \frac {dB}{dt}$ and this is the induced emf in the loop (Faraday).

If the loop is conducting then the induced emf induces a current in the circuit which you have stated to be anticlockwise in the top left hand corner and the same current flow though each part of the loop although there may be ambiguity about direction if one tries to use the terms anticlockwise and clockwise for each segment of the loop.

At each part of the loop the induced current produces a magnetic field which is upwards **within** the loop ie in the opposite direction to the increasing external magnetic field.
This is Lenz's law in action as the induced current is trying to reduce the rate at which the magnetic field (and hence the magnetic flux) is changing within the loop.
That is happening for **all** segments of the conducting loop and so those bits of the loop where the current seems to go clockwise still produce a magnetic field in opposition to the changing external magnetic field.

So the shape of the loop does not matter.
What does matter is the enclosed area $A$, the rate of change of external magnetic field (and the resistance of the loop).

Comment: So whichever direction of current allows for more induced opposing flux *inside the loop* ,take it, is that right?

Comment: Yes, each part of the induced current carrying loop provides opposition the the changing external magnetic field.

Answer (score 3):

When the B-field is applied as indicated in the picture, according to the Maxwell-Faraday law:

$$\nabla\times E = -\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}$$

In order to know the direction of the induced E-field, the curl follows the right hand rule. So, because of the minus sign, the conventional current flows counterclockwise.

The only role of the inner part of the loop is to reduce its area $S$, reducing the magnetic flow. If the same length of wire formed a circle for example, $S$ would be bigger. The integral form of the equation above is:

$$\oint_{\partial \Sigma} \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\ell}  = - \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \iint_{\Sigma} \mathbf{B} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{S}$$

Or, renaming some terms:
$$\epsilon= -(d\phi/dt)= -(d(BS)/dt)  $$

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know physics to that degree. As I understand it, a closed loop forms current according to lenz's law to oppose changing magnetic flux in it- the current can be calculated using the right-hand rule. According to this, the current would be counterclockwise, as given by the right-hand rule. Why consider them as different loops, and why consider area?

Comment: Hi Claudio. You second equation is not "integral form" at all.Your first equation implies there is a time changing magnetic field, but the OP has not indicated if this is true. Apart from that your answer looks OK. You should change the statement "_The integral form of the equation above is_" to something like "_the expression for the induced emf is ..._".since that statement is totally false and may confuse beginners. I have down-voted for now but will be happy to up-vote if you correct the error since there technically is nothing wrong with your answer.

Comment: @josephh I don't understand you. The second equation *is* the "integral form" of the Maxwell-Faraday law. It may be just semantics, but could you expand a little bit more on what do you call "integral form" of Maxwell's equations ? Plus, of course the magnetic field is implied to be time varying, overwise there would be no induction and no emf, since the magnetic flux would be constant through the loop.

Comment: The question has been edited. Check edits before asking silly questions. +1 vote for Claudio

Answer (score 1):

Well you are right in your understanding that there is only one loop. Anyone who has used the terms "inner" and "outer" must specify what he/she means.

There is one more thing about your question. You seem to have a bit of problem with the concept here. Let me explain.

[image: Diagram]

This is what your loop looks like with the magnetic field. Now the current that is induced in this is ***zero***. The reason for this is Faraday's law that governs electromagnetic induction.

$$\epsilon = -N\frac{d\phi}{dt}$$

where,
$\epsilon$ is the induced electromotive force (or more appropriately voltage)

$\phi$ is the flux of the magnetic field through the loop

$N$ is the number of loops.

For our case, $N$ is $1$.

Now if our loop is a conductor, we will observe current. And in such a case, how do we determine the direction of our current? The magnitude is given by ohm's law.

There are two ways which you can use to arrive at the direction.

**Method 1: Using Lenz's law**

According to Lenz's law, the induced current will be such that the magnetic field due to it will oppose the original magnetic field. If you are a high-school student, it is highly recommended you use this law because of its simplicity.

**Method 2: Using Faraday's Law**

Faraday's law is self sufficient in determining the direction of the current. For this you need to have a look at one of the Maxwell's equation:

$$\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = -\frac{\partial{\mathbf{B}}}{\partial{t}}$$

The mathematical complexity should be evident by now. However, if you are well acquainted with vector calculus, you may proceed as follows:

You have the Magnetic Field, therefore you can obtain the Electric field in its vector form. After doing so(it will be a lengthy process) you can analyze the effect of the electric field on an electron in the conductor. With the direction of electron movement you can get the direction of current.

Now use these laws in the case you have mentioned, and you will see that the current is zero.

Hint: The magnetic field and the area of the loop are both constant with no time dependence.

Hope this helps you! Feel free to comment and ask any questions you have!

---

**EDIT 1:**

Okay so in the comments the OP asked about why the current is zero. This edit is regarding that comment.

Since you want to know why the current is zero, you must take a look at the laws governing the magnitude of the current.

In Faradays law, we see the term $\phi$ which is the flux of the magnetic field *through the loop*. This flux is given by,

$$\phi=\mathbf{B.A}$$

Now we have three quantities that may change with time:

1. The Magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$
2. The magnitude of Area of the loop $A$
3. The angle between the normal to the loop surface(direction of the Area vector) and the magnetic field.

Now look at your case to see if $\phi$ which is given by the above expression is a function of time. You will find the answer.

Comment: You did not answer the question as to _why_ the direction changes and there is a current because the loop is rotating. It would not make any sense for the OP to say there is a current if B,A are constant and the loop is not changing direction. -1 vote for now.

Comment: Down voting my answer is not going to solve anything.Fix yours and I will up vote it.

Comment: No where does the OP mention that the loop is rotating. Mostly in cases like these, the  magnetic field changes with time. I simply did not make assumptions instead wrote an answer that helps the OP answer the question for whichever case he wants to.

Comment: No the magnetic field does not rotate. It is in one direction shown in the diagram. You are mistaken and you down voted a correct answer. smh.

Comment: I think you really need to learn how to read and also learn some manners on how to behave on an online platform. Firstly, I said that the "loop" is not rotating. Secondly, it was you who downvoted an answer that was more general. StackExchange is not for spoonfeeding. It is for helping others learn physics.

Comment: Moreover I have answered what the OP has asked. I do not make "assumptions" because, I believe that there is no such thing as a bad question. If the OP edits it, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Then please explain why the OP mentions there is a current the wire. Does it just magically appear? And bad manners is down voting out of spite rather than bad physics.

Comment: Bad manners is how you talk. Now, coming to why the OP says there is a current: 1. It could be that, the OP has actually forgot to mention that the magnetic field was changing, or the loop was being stretched or that the loop was rotating. 2. The OP has a flaw in his concept and therefore missed this point and actually feels there would be current just by inducing magnetic field

Comment: My answer can help him solve all the 3 cases: The area being changed, the magnetic field changing, the loop rotating. My answer is therefore more versatile and will answer the OP's question no matter what the case. Therefore what I have written is not bad physics. You have just taken that one case where its rotating. You can't assume what *you like*, you have to answer taking into account assumptions the OP has given. If there is missing information, your answer must cover all possible cases and yours does not. Hence the downvote. People who live in glass houses must not throw stones at others

Comment: In my comment there is a correction in the last line, "just by introducing the magnetic field" instead of "inducing"

Comment: Does there exist a unique E such that $\nabla \times E = \partial_t B$?

Comment: @Buraian that question is vast enough to deserve a question of its own. But since you asked, you can refer this paper: https://www.wtamu.edu/~cbaird/SuppMaxwellUniqueness.pdf

Comment: I only know enough to use lenz's law; why exactly is current 0-using it- and what have I understood wrong? Aren't currents set up in closed loops, of which there's just the one, implying it's an anticlockwise current? The answer actually is an anticlockwise current and not zero; the reasoning behind it seemed weird (involving two loops), which is why I asked.

Comment: @HarryHolmes please have a look at the edited answer

Comment: You need to use Lenz's law only if there is a current. If the magnitude itself is 0, there is no sense in using Lenz's law

Comment: @Tesla's Coil: I get the part about change of $\phi$ being 0; I should have been clearer about the question asking about the instant at which the magnetic field is suddenly introduced into the system. In that case-since I'm a high school student- my actual question was on how you're supposed to use Lenz's law here. It seems not to be as simple as usual; it isn't the type of coil we usually evaluate. How do we use Lenz's law on this?

Comment: Okay. So two things: 1. When the magnetic field is suddenly introduced into the system, it is like changing magnetic field from 0 to B. This change is sudden however. Due to the change being sudden, the time interval is infinitesimally small. Therefore we speak about the total charge flown which would be $\frac{\Delta \phi}{R}$ if $R$ is the resistance of the loop. So that should clear up the case where the magnetic field is suddenly introduced.

Comment: 2. On how to use Lenz's Law over here: First notice the shape of the loop. It isn't a square or a circle. But the current will flow in either anticlockwise or clockwise direction. The magnetic field will either be into the plane or out of the plane(if it is in the plane, flux is 0). Now use the right hand rule to determine the direction of current. It will be either clockwise or anticlockwise. It will flow along that direction along the loop. Every loop has anticlockwise and clockwise direction no matter what the shape.

Comment: I hope this clears your doubt. Please take a moment off to upvote and accept this answer if you liked it.